# AMD Driver on Ubuntu 12.04LTS: PC Running in Low Graphics Mode

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, lts

my big problem is, that i cannot get the AMD Driver working on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.
After install the Run with Terminal, it says "PC Running in Low Graphics Mode. Please Configure Driver Yourself!"

Any Ides how to fix this?

I've tried almost everything out which I could fin in the Internet! Just one Site worked for me, but I wasn't able to relocate it again.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!